# Does Salesforce or any third party maintain a list of which formulas work in list views?

Tags: formula, list, user, list-view, lightninglistview

I am looking for a list of formulas that work in list views.  For example, you can set **"last login" = LAST QUARTER** on the user list view, which is very helpful for generating a list of users who have recently logged in.  Some but not all formulas work in these fields, does anyone know if there is a list of these formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a list maintained in the [Relative Date Filter Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5). The current list is as follows:

- YESTERDAY
- TODAY
- TOMORROW
- LAST WEEK
- THIS WEEK
- NEXT WEEK
- LAST n WEEKS
- NEXT n WEEKS
- n WEEKS AGO
- LAST MONTH
- THIS MONTH
- NEXT n MONTHS
- LAST n MONTHS
- n MONTHS AGO
- NEXT MONTH
- LAST 90 DAYS
- NEXT 90 DAYS
- LAST n DAYS
- NEXT n DAYS
- n DAYS AGO
- LAST QUARTER
- THIS QUARTER
- NEXT QUARTER
- LAST n QUARTERS
- NEXT n QUARTERS
- n QUARTERS AGO
- LAST YEAR
- THIS YEAR
- NEXT YEAR
- n YEARS AGO
- LAST n YEARS
- NEXT n YEARS
- LAST FISCAL QUARTER
- THIS FISCAL QUARTER
- NEXT FISCAL QUARTER
- LAST n FISCAL QUARTERS
- NEXT n FISCAL QUARTERS
- n FISCAL QUARTERS AGO
- LAST FISCAL YEAR
- THIS FISCAL YEAR
- NEXT FISCAL YEAR
- LAST n FISCAL YEARS
- NEXT n FISCAL YEARS
- n FISCAL YEARS AGO

You can check the documentation for new filters when/if they come out.

Comment: Thank you, I found the documentation shortly after posting at the link here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5.  Do you happen to know if you can do a LIMIT or a > 10 type operators in these views?

Comment: @GedAWizardofEarthSea No, list views do not support limits.